# inserting images into a table using macro (vba powerpoint 2010)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've written a vba script which basically inserts a table into a slide with text"Sample text in the cell", Now i want to add images to the cells of the table depending on the size of a table from a folder.

Basically if it's 5X3 table then it should take 15 images from the folder and arrange it into the cell with the image file name. The output which i want is this:

[image]

the code which i wrote is :

```
Sub NativeTable()
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape As Shape     ' code to create table in present slide
    Dim pptPres As presentation
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim iColumn As Integer
    Dim oShapeInsideTable As Shape

    Set pptPres = ActivePresentation
    With pptPres
        Set pptSlide = .Slides.Add(.Slides.Count, ppLayoutBlank)
    End With
    With pptSlide.Shapes
         Set pptShape = .AddTable(NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=5, Left:=30, _
                                Top:=110, Width:=660, Height:=320)
    End With
    With pptShape.Table
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count
                With .Cell(iRow, iColumn).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                    .Text = "Sample text in Cell"
                    With .Font
                        .Name = "Verdana"
                        .Size = "14"
                    End With
                End With
            Next iColumn
        Next iRow
    End With
End Sub
```

So how can i do it please help me with this and the image should be resizable(if that is possible) please help me with this
Is this possible i've checked the msdn object reference but there is no option for inserting picture in a cell

Answer (score 0):

Insert as cell background. Select a cell > Design > Shading > Picture

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but here's the code in case anyone else needs it.  Just make sure to change the variables in parenthesis to fit your needs.

```
PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("table_1").Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.Fill.UserPicture ("location_of_picture_file")
```